# Can I have a machine in a DNS subdomain, but Active Directory main domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2003, active-directory, samba

I've just started virtualising some Linux servers, and want them to have DNS names like this:

```
name.vm.company.internal
```

Our DNS is hosted on Windows 2003 Active Directory, so most machines are currently named:

```
name.company.internal
```

These boxes are joined to the company.internal AD domain using Samba 3, but they don't make dynamic DNS updates - I'd like them to so that I don't have to manage their main DNS separately.

To achieve this, will I need to create a separate AD subdomain of `vm.company.internal` or can I get them to update their DNS correctly while remaining manageable through the `company.internal` domain?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming I understood the question completely and I'm thinking clear enough this morning...

If the Linux servers are AD joined already to company.internal (which is a bad AD FQDN but I digress), then unless you want to deal with a child domain in AD for `vm.company.internal` you're best bet is to simply create a DNS subdomain inside DNS only and create static entries for those Linux servers as `name.vm.company.internal`.

The servers IPs shouldn't really be dynamic, so static records in the DNS subdomain should suffice.

You will still be able to see them as their existing `name.company.internal` as well, which will make AD happy enough.

Comment: I agree with you on the FQDN, but one step at a time...

Comment: So no way to dynamically update a DNS subdomain automatically? The main reason I ask is that we are preparing to move a lot of these things around to clean things up.

Comment: I'm not sure on the Linux client idea.  For a Windows client, it should be possible under the TCP/IP advanced settings if you are specifying the DNS connection suffix that it would dynamically update the subdomain in DNS.  But for me personally, I don't rely on dynamic updates of non-DHCP clients, I prefer statically controlling entries for servers and devices with static IPs.